# jquery tooltip+live

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have this code

```
$(".tooltip").each(function(){
        var tooltip = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $(this).live("mousemove",function(e){
             $("#tooltip").html(tooltip).show();
        }).live("mouseout",function(){
            $("#tooltip").hide().empty();
        });
    });
```

It works good, but what with elements that are loaded dynamically by ajax?
Thanks

Comment: side note: .live() is deprecated and shouldn't be used. In the case of older (<1.7) jQuery use .delegate - otherwise .on should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be in a .each()? Will this work:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $('#tooltip').html(tooltip).show();
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $('#tooltip').hide();
    }
}, '.tooltip');
```

Added a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/uNvB3/)

Comment: yes it must be each, because with this visitor can change tooltips in his console

Comment: Ok - well this should still work; just place it in the .each()

Comment: @dontHaveName Added a jsFiddle example. BTW - I wouldn't try to code for people using console. This is client-side content that only affects that person - if they want to play around let them. Even with your code up top I can change the tooltip by .die() or .off() and re-attaching an event.

Comment: yes ok, I will not try to avoid it..but in other example if am I sending data like this <a href="#" lightbox="data"></a>, and I don't want to show what am I sending, it will be better if I can hide it(I have secured it in php file, but will be better if a little bit in js too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.ready function this will run your function after all the elements are loaded.
i.e .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tooltip").each(function(){
        var tooltip = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $(this).live("mousemove",function(e){
             $("#tooltip").html(tooltip).show();
        }).live("mouseout",function(){
            $("#tooltip").hide().empty();
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: I wrote it bad :(, I mean elements that are loaded by ajax, so this solution will not help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to ensure the events are transmitted to elements added later :

```
$(document).on('mousemove', ".tooltip", function(e){
     this.title = "";
     $("#tooltip").html(this.tooltip).show();
}).on('mouseout', ".tooltip", function(e){
     this.title = "";
     $("#tooltip").html(this.tooltip).hide();
});
```

This will apply to all `.tooltip` elements. No need for your `each`.

Comment: With this too, visitors can simply change the tooltip :( and I don't want to allow this

Comment: You **can't** guard against users changing your page in their console. Never never never try to implement client side protections.

Comment: yes, but if is it possible, it will be harder for "newbies" to change tooltip text

Comment: I don't think you'll find many users able to change that in the console but just at the right level of newbiness to be slowed by this kind of protection...

Comment: is there any better protection for this?

Comment: What do you want to avoid ? If you want to protect against hackers, do it server side.

Comment: I want to avoid only changing tooltips, nothing with server side

Comment: Why ? If a user hacks the page in its own browser and computer to change its tooltips, what's the problem ?

Comment: it's not big problem..but if is it possible to avoid it, I must do it

Comment: Just store your tool tip text in a database and use ajax to periodically check it against what is on the page. Change accordingly... OR, avoid this silly overkill and just let the users screw with their own pages. Refreshing the page reverts the changes, no one else will see them, no worries.